# Split data separated by comma into lists in python

Tags: python

my dataframe df looks like this

```
Row_ID Codes
=============
1      A123,B456,C678
2      X359,C678,F23
3      J3,D24,J36,K994
```

I want to put all Codes in a list

something like this

```
['A123', 'B456', 'C678'],['X359', 'C678', 'F23'], ['J3', 'D24', 'J36', 'K994']
```

I did this

```
# an empty list
CodeList = [] 
for i in df['Codes']: 
  CodeList.append(list(i))
```

but what I get is this

```
['A','1','2','3','B'....
```

How can I do it the right way as mentioned above?

Comment: Remove list(i) from the line CodeList.append(list(i)). Just keep CodeList.append(i)

Comment: Variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, not `camelCase` or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like many of the other answers here might just be plain wrong. (Edit: Currently, they all are)

This code does work:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Codes': ['A123,B456,C678', 'X359,C678,F23', 'J3,D24,J36,K994']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

codes_list = df['Codes'].str.split(',').tolist()
```

`codes_list` looks like:

```py
[['A123', 'B456', 'C678'], ['X359', 'C678', 'F23'], ['J3', 'D24', 'J36', 'K994']]
```

Note that this solution is idiomatic Pandas, whereas explicit loops should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try spliting using the following:

```
CodeList.append(i.split(','))
```

Comment: Why the extra `[ ]`?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I think he wants array of arrays

Comment: I just tested it, the `[ ]` are unnecessary.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm thinking of += instead of append. thanks @AlexanderCécile

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"Codes": ["A123, B456, C678", "X359, C678, F23", "J3, D24, J36, K994"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = [a.split(", ") for a in df["Codes"]]
print(result)
```

output

```
[['A123', 'B456', 'C678'], ['X359', 'C678', 'F23'], ['J3', 'D24', 'J36', 'K994']]
```

Comment: The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) advise against using `.values`.

Comment: Also, is it just the way it was copied into the post or is that output list different from the one in OP’s post?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile good point. I updated my result by removing values. So instead I'm just iterating over series values. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I'm quite certain that this output is incorrect. OP's desired output is `[['A123', 'B456', 'C678'],['X359', 'C678', 'F23'], ['J3', 'D24', 'J36', 'K994']]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 2), columns=list('AB'))
print(df.head())
print(df.values.tolist())
```

output:

```
[[-0.2645782053241853, 0.5022937587041725], [1.624868960959602, 0.5086915380333786], [1.3593608874498997, 0.7077939622903995]]
```

Comment: The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) advise against using `.values`.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile alright, it's usually good to have more than solution.

Comment: I said nothing to the contrary. We shouldn’t promote bad practices “because they’re different”, however, especially when there exists a good alternative. Also, I’m pretty sure that code doesn’t even produce the right result.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Okay

Comment: Yeah no i’m quite certain that this isn’t correct. Your code is literally just converting that DataFrame to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the list from line `CodeList.append(list(i))`

```
CodeList = [] 
for i in df['Codes']: 
   CodeList.append(i.split(','))
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this is incorrect. In any case, it should probably just be written `df[‘Codes’].tolist()`.

Comment: I just checked, this is indeed incorrect. The output of  `CodeList` will be `['A123, B456, C678', 'X359, C678, F23', 'J3, D24, J36, K994']`.